# Permit user to switch to application user in sudoers

Tags: linux, security, sudo, jenkins, sudoers

As an effort to extend security on our main job server I would like to tinker around with rights and restrict all useless permissions.
Especially bothers Jenkins running as `jenkins ALL=(ALL)` bothers me running on our server. We use him to run applications and scripts periodically as application user(s).

I would like to enable Jenkins to `su` only to specific users, or better, to a specific group like `su -u [member of group system_users]`.

Is this possible with sudoers permissions? Can it be done elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I added links to the man page to be helpful, please don't feel judged. The sudoers man page is seriously difficult if you don't already know what you're looking for. Hope this helps. I must recommend a book by Michael W. Lucas on **Sudo Mastery**. It was the primer I needed.

User aliases shown here: https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html#EXAMPLES

```
User_Alias THEUSERS = user1, user2, user3
```

Runas user definition: https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html#Runas_Spec

```
jenkins ALL=(THEUSERS) ALL
```